# Можно ли заменять ссылки на документацию на «более хорошие»?

Tags: поддержка, документация

Мне кажется, что для каждого языка программирования сайты с документаций делятся на «более хорошие» и «менее хорошие».

Например для C++:

- более хорошие:

  - [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com)
- менее хорошие:

  - [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com)

Или для JavaScript:

- более хорошие:

  - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/)
  - [learn.javascript.ru](http://learn.javascript.ru)
  - [webreference](https://webref.ru/)
- менее хорошие:

  - [javascript.ru](http://javascript.ru)
  - [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru)
  - [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com)

(субъективные) преимущества «более хороших» сайтов:

- достаточно часто доступна русская версия
- более актуальная информация
- иногда больше информации

На некоторых «менее хороших» сайтах даже может быть написано, что новая версия сайта доступна по адресу ..., и указан адрес сайта из списка «более хороших», например:

- [javascript.ru](http://javascript.ru) → [learn.javascript.ru](http://learn.javascript.ru)
- [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru) → [webreference](https://webref.ru/)

**Вопрос:** можно ли заменять в ответах ссылки на «менее хорошие» сайты ссылками на «более хорошие» или это разделение вообще неправильное?

Comment: "...а судьи кто?"

Comment: ну для C++ и JavaScript то разделение которое предложено в вопросе

Comment: @D-side: Например, сообщество. Если спецы по C++ постановят, что cplusplus.com — фу и бяка, то так тому и быть. Для этого кто-то, кому сообщество доверяет, должен расписать все недостатки этого сайта на Мете, так чтобы аж всех убедить. Да что я рассказываю, вы ж долгожитель сайта!

Comment: cplusplus.com лутше. Быстрее открывается (важно во время работы).

Answer (score 5):

Во-первых, зачем заменять, если можно дополнять? Во-вторых, лучше не трогать чужие ответы - вдруг человек хотел дать ссылку именно туда, куда дал? Ну и наконец, почему бы просто не добавить ссылку в комментарии к ответу?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы думаете ваша правка улучшает ответ, не изменяя его смысл, то конечно можно правку предлагать. [Почему кто-то может редактировать мои сообщения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) Автор ответа может по незнанию общепризнано худшую ссылку использовать. К примеру, [ссылка на w3schools (особенно в прошлом) — это преступление](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280478/4279).

Если вы сомневаетесь, что однозначно ответ будет улучшен правкой, то оставьте комментарий под ответом о том, что автор ответа может вашу правку отклонить свободно (чтобы это как конфликт не воспринималось).

Даже если вы уверены в своём выборе, автор ответа может другие предпочтения иметь. Не вносите правку, если она изменяет смысл ответа с точки зрения его автора.